# show form in dynamic column when iterating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a long form which has mixed type of column. I mean some field will be of width 100% some field will be around 33% so that i can show 3 fields in a column and so on. This I could do without iterating, but **how can it be done if the fields are shown with iteration to avoid code repetition?** I have created a sandbox either and I am not using third party css framework like bootstrap just a flex or may be grid would work.

Here is how i have tried:

```
const formFields = [
  { id: 1, name: "first_name", component: TextField, label: "First Name" },
  { id: 1, name: "last_name", component: TextField, label: "Last Name" },
  { id: 1, name: "age", component: TextField, label: "Age" },
  { id: 1, name: "city", component: TextField, label: "City" },
  { id: 1, name: "state", component: TextField, label: "State" },
  { id: 1, name: "country", component: TextField, label: "Country" }
];

const FlexibleForm = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Form onSubmit={() => console.log("something")}>
        <FlexRow>
          <FlexColumn size={12}>
            {formFields.map(({ id, name, label, component }) => {
              return (
                <Field
                  key={id}
                  name={name}
                  label={label}
                  component={component}
                />
              );
            })}
          </FlexColumn>
        </FlexRow>
        <h2>Another without iteration</h2>
        <FlexRow>
          <FlexColumn size={6}>
            <Field name="first_name" label="First Name" component={TextField} />
          </FlexColumn>
          <FlexColumn size={6}>
            <Field name="last_name" label="Last Name" component={TextField} />
          </FlexColumn>
        </FlexRow>
        <FlexRow>
          <FlexColumn size={12}>
            <Field name="age" label="Age" component={TextField} />
          </FlexColumn>
        </FlexRow>
        <FlexRow>
          <FlexColumn size={4}>
            <Field name="city" label="City" component={TextField} />
          </FlexColumn>
          <FlexColumn size={4}>
            <Field name="state" label="State" component={TextField} />
          </FlexColumn>
          <FlexColumn size={4}>
            <Field name="country" label="Country" component={TextField} />
          </FlexColumn>
        </FlexRow>
      </Form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "form"
})(FlexibleForm);

export const FlexRow = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  div {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
`;

export const FlexColumn = styled.div`
  width: ${props => (props.size / 12) * 100}vw;
`;
```

Here is the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/l7lm1qp0pq

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: question is marked as bold now. How can i show the fields in varying column using iteration, which i did without using iteration?

Comment: Maybe in your `FlexRow` component, you can add some props like an array of objects like `[{name: "city", "label": "city", "component": <TextField />}, {name: "state", "label": "state", "component": <TextField />}, .....]` and then create a condition to check how many items are in the array, if they're three items then create 3 flex column with size 4. Let's say you call your props `itemsInRow`, then in `FlexRow` you can write something like `this.props.itemsInRow.map( () => <FlexColumn size={Math.round(12/this.props.itemsInRow.length)}> etc.

Comment: can you reproduce an example with your concept by forking my code from sandbox, please?

Comment: There are a few solutions below, but I would like to paraphrase the great Ian Malcolm "You were so preoccupied with whether or not you could, that you didn't stop to think if you should" Is keeping this code "dynamic" solving anything, or just adding more complexity to your code?

Answer (score 3):

This is `<FlexRow>` component

```
const FlexRow = props => {
 return (
   <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    {props.elements.map((element, index) => {
       const obj = element.component;
       return (
         <FlexColumn key={index} size={Math.round(12 / props.elements.length)}>
           <Field
             name={element.name}
             label={element.label}
             component={obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]}
           />
         </FlexColumn>
       );
    })}
  </div>
 );
};
```

This is `<FlexColumn>` component

```
const FlexColumn = styled.div`
   width: ${props => (props.size / 12) * 100}vw;
   margin-right: 10px;
`;
```

Your `<FlexibleForm>` should look like this :

```
const FlexibleForm = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Form onSubmit={() => console.log("something")}>
            <FlexRow
              elements={[
                { name: "first_name", label: "First Name", component: {TextField} },
                { name: "last_name", label: "Last Name", component: {TextField} }
              ]}
            />
            <FlexRow
              elements={[{ name: "age", label: "Age", component: {TextField} }]}
            />
            <FlexRow
              elements={[
                { name: "city", label: "City", component: {TextField} },
                { name: "state", label: "State", component: {TextField} },
                { name: "country", label: "Country", component: {TextField} }
              ]}
            />
          </Form>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
```

The component `<FlexRow>` will loop inside his props `elements` and will create a `<FlexColumn>` with the good size with the good attributes.
Litteraly, it did loop inside the props `elements` which is an array and return the size (12 divided by the number of rows you have), you can change this value if you want with a simple condition like :

`element.size ? element.size : Math.round(12 / props.elements.length)` 
and add a `size` element in your `elements` array

`{ name: "first_name", label: "First Name", size: 6, component: {TextField} }`

Then it add the label and the name. And finally it add the component you choosed, in this example it's `<TextField>`

This will avoid you from repeating your code.
Here's the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ovnj6vp3k5) to show you the example !

Wish I did helped you.

Comment: I like this solution, but I think the problem I am having (with the question, really) is that avoiding repeating code in this instance add to the complexity greatly. The solution I like the most was the original. it's explicit, easy to alter and debug, and a new developer coming in can read it..

Comment: @Beaulne yes I think you're right, the only issue I see with his iteration which is way easier than mine is that he can't choose the size of the field. I prefer to use `<Component>` and `<ComponentItem>` for me it's easier to read and add properties

Answer (score 0):

There is no much point of using flex if you are not using flex-wrap.

If you want to do it with simple float:

```
const formFields = [
  { id: 1, name: "first_name", component: TextField, label: "First Name",size: 6 },
  { id: 1, name: "last_name", component: TextField, label: "Last Name", size: 6 },
  { id: 1, name: "age", component: TextField, label: "Age", size: 12 },
  { id: 1, name: "city", component: TextField, label: "City", size: 4 },
  { id: 1, name: "state", component: TextField, label: "State", size: 4 },
  { id: 1, name: "country", component: TextField, label: "Country", size: 4 }
];

const Form = styled.form`
  width: 100%;
`;

const FlexColumn = styled.div`
  float: left;
  width: ${props => (props.size / 12) * 100}%;
`;

const FlexibleForm = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Form onSubmit={() => console.log("something")}>
      {formFields.map(({ id, name, label, component, size }) => {
        return (
          <FlexColumn size={size}>
            <Field key={id} name={name} label={label} component={component} />
          </FlexColumn>
        );
      })}
    </Form>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: Does this work without wrapping `<FlexColumn>` in a  `<FlexRow>`?

Comment: i do not wrap those